Integration of analytic function
It is the continuation of the question:
Complexity of analytic functions and integrals.
Given an input integer $t$ and a sequence of analytic functions $f_n(\cdots(f_0(x))$, with parameters $t$ itself, $a_0, \dots a_n$ which are polytime computable with respect to the length of $t$, the functions are also polytime computable and the functions are analytic on the interval $[a, t]$, $a<t$.
Is the computation of antiderivative of the $f_n(\cdots (f_0(x))$ polynomial time computable with respect to the length of t, if $x$ belongs to the interval [a, t]? Does not the works of Müller and Ker - I. Ko guarantee this?
